# Finding the non-permissible values of $x$ for $\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)} = \frac{1-\cos(x)}{\tan(x)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Find the non permissible values of $x$
> $$\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)} = \frac{1-\cos(x)}{\tan(x)}$$

On the left side, $\cos(x) \not= -1$, so $x \not= \pi + 2n\pi,\;n \in\mathbb{Z}.$

On the right side, $\tan(x) \not= 0$, so $x \not= \dfrac{\pi n}{2},\;n \in\mathbb{Z}.$

So then with these two domains how can you determine the restrictions on the equation?

Comment: Note that $\tan(x)=0$ if and only if $\sin(x)=0,$ which occurs at $n\pi,$ not $n\pi/2.$ Your $\cos(x)$ criterion is correct. Hint for solution: union.

Comment: @AdrianKeister isn’t tanx undefined when cosx = 0 as well? Or should I just convert all of the functions into donc and cosx?

Comment: Well, note that $\dfrac{1-\cos(x)}{\tan(x)}=\dfrac{(1-\cos(x))\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}.$ In the limit, at least, the places where $\cos(x)=0$ make the whole expression $0.$ It might depend on the context whether those values are permissible or not.

Comment: what about $\cos(x)\ne 0$?

Comment: Well I suppose @Adrian's limit argument shouldn't hold up, for we are dealing with exact values here. $\cos x=0$ should also be excluded.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Fair enough.